# How to set Z-Index on multiple esri shape layers

Tags: javascript, leaflet, z-index

I'm trying to build a [leaflet JS](http://leafletjs.com/) map 0.7.7 with [leaflet.shapefile](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet.shapefile) plugin, this allows me to use zip files containing the shape files from esri and project these onto the map.

**I'm having great difficulties ordering the various layers Z-indexes.**

Here is my [my test version](http://eastsuffolk.4coffshore.com/map/test.htm) (see updated info below) and code.

I have tried the following, but i cant get it to work:

```
Layer1.setZIndex(1);    // Area Action Plan
Layer2.setZIndex(2);    // Enterprise Zone
Layer3.setZIndex(3);    // Local Development Order
Layer4.setZIndex(4);    // Properties
```

I also tried

```
Layer1.bringToBack();    // Area Action Plan
Layer2.bringToBack();    // Enterprise Zone
Layer3.bringToBack();    // Local Development Order
Layer4.bringToFront();   // Properties
```

and even tried

```
m.on("overlayadd", function (event) {
    Layer1.bringToBack();    // Area Action Plan
    Layer2.bringToBack();    // Enterprise Zone
    Layer3.bringToBack();    // Local Development Order
    Layer4.bringToFront();   // Properties
});
```

Currently it's at random, not all polygons are clickable or seem to be behind a layer. When I manually turn Layer4 (properties) **off** and **on** again via the layer switch control  (top right corner), it brings Layer4 to the top and i'm able to click on these areas (yellow), however when loading or reloading the map (pageload) it seem like it has a mind of it's own

**My ideal solution would be that layer4 (properties) is always on top, over any of the other layers and able to click on these.**

Here is a screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Could someone please help me or advice me on, what i'm doing wrong and how to resolve this issue. thank you.

** **updated info:** **

I have followed the recommendations made in the comments, no luck yet

- Upgraded to version:  **[1.0.2](http://leafletjs.com/download.html)**
- Created a `pane` for each layer and added it to their style like so:

  ```
  m.createPane('Layer1');
  m.getPane('Layer1').style.zIndex = 399;
  // Added this to the layer style.
  pane: 'Layer1'
  ```
- **Saved it as a [new test page](http://eastsuffolk.4coffshore.com/map/test1.htm)**.

However the code is not displaying any layers anymore, they seem to appear for a split second and then disappeared again.

Comment: This sounds related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163212/leaflet-any-way-to-add-another-layergroup-on-top-of-a-heatmap-layer

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178622/z-index-of-geojsons-and-imageoverlays-in-leaflet - the solution described there should be applicable to `L.Shapefile` layers as well.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak, i tried the link and solution however no luck, now going to try what IvanSanchez suggested, i will update the post with my findings.

Comment: Hi guys, i tried both provided answers but still no luck, I created a new page and upgraded to leaflet 1.0.2: [here](http://eastsuffolk.4coffshore.com/map/test1.htm) but this is not showing any of the layers any more, what am i doing wrong

Comment: The code looks good, but I think there is a string with unclosed/unescaped quotes.

Comment: Also, please be aware of this bug: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4277 - this means that you should have the `pane` option as part of the return value of your `style` functions.

Comment: I have changed and update the latest [test version](http://eastsuffolk.4coffshore.com/map/test1.htm) and have placed the `pane:` in each `style` function of it's layer. when you say 'string with unclosed/unescaped quotes' do you mean within the data table attributes of the esri shape or in the code itself ? Thanks again, I really appreciate your help and guidance.